# unrecognized selector sent to instance after Swift 4.2 migration

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I just migrated my project from Swift 3.0 to Swift 4.2 and I started getting this error.

This same method is being called from several classes, but only one is throwing the exception. Any ideas what may have changed in a single class during a Swift migration that may be causing this issue?

> 2020-03-04 09:53:42.552405-0500 Lake Observer[13974:1234549]
>   -[Lake_Observer.LocationChangeController reusablePickerViewController:didChooseValue:forCtrl:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x1040ca800 2020-03-04 09:53:42.554410-0500
>   Lake Observer[13974:1234549] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Lake_Observer.LocationChangeController
>   reusablePickerViewController:didChooseValue:forCtrl:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x1040ca800'

This is where the exception is occurring. (RecorderReusablePicker)

```
- (void) buttonIsPressed:(UIButton *)paramSender{

        NSMutableArray *retArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:array.count];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
            [retArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[genericPicker selectedRowInComponent:i]]];
        }
        [callingReference reusablePickerViewController:self didChooseValue:[[RecorderReusableResult alloc] initWithArray:retArray clearValue:NO] forCtrl:callingControlReference];
}
```

Picker is created here. (LocationChangeController)

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if (textField == editTextWaterBody) {
        let waterbodyArray: NSArray? = NSArray(objects: waterbodyNames)
        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.present(RecorderReusablePicker (dataArray: waterbodyArray as? [Any], widthArray: nil, inInitialIndexArray: [savedWaterbodyIndex], reference: self, andControlRef: editTextWaterBody, andTitle: "Please select your waterbody", showSelection: true, allowPanZoom: false), animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

And the method when returning from the picker.

```
func reusablePickerViewController(_ reusablePickerViewController: RecorderReusablePicker!, didChooseValue retVal: RecorderReusableResult!, forCtrl outCtrl: Any!) {
    reusablePickerViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Again, there are other classes that have the exact same methods to create and return from the Picker, but only one causing the exception.

Comment: If you change `func reusablePickerViewController` to `@objc func reusablePickerViewController` does that fix it?

Comment: yes sir, it surely does. many thanks.

Comment: this makes sense now, because my LocationChangeController class was prefixed as @objc, but the other classes were not

Comment: That's excellent, I'll give that as an answer. Could be useful to others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
func reusablePickerViewController
```

to

```
@objc func reusablePickerViewController
```

The migration from Swift 3 to Swift 4.2 changed the rules for how instance members are exposed to Objective-C. In Swift 3, they were exposed by default. In Swift 4.2, you must expose them explicitly; otherwise, Objective-C cannot see them — which is exactly what is happening to you. The method is there, but Objective-C thinks it isn't, so it crashes with an Unrecognized Selector exception.

Comment: As a follow up question, is there any way to figure out which other methods throughout my code might need to be explicitly exposed?

Comment: Everything that is not already exposed must be exposed explicitly. By "already exposed" I mean, for example, that something like `viewDidLoad` is already exposed because it is an override of a UIViewController method, and UIViewController _already_ belongs to Objective-C / Cocoa, so it knows about it. Anything that you write that is _not_ an override and _not_ declared in an Objective-C protocol is hidden by default.